# Issues with characters in PHP array when converting to JSON

Tags: php, json

I've got a whole variety of data in a database, with strings, integers & special characters.  I need to get this into a JSON output, which I am able to do using `json_encode`.

However, when validating this JSON, it fails because some of the data contains things like double quotes, brackets etc, which break it, for example:

```
"description":"Allow support for "trends" and other processes"
```

The double quotes around trends breaks it.

Is there anyway I can pre-pare the data in my array before encoding it? I don't have the ability to edit the data, so it needs to be done after the SQL query to gather it.

I'm doing it along the lines of:

```
    $data = array();    
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($execute))
        {
            $data[] = array(
                "description" => $row["Descrption"],
            );
        }
```

Then:

```
print json_encode($data);
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

var_dump:

```
["description"]=> string(79) "Allow support for "trends" and other processes"
```

Comment: `json_encode` should be escaping the double quotes like so: `"description":"Allow support for \"trends\" and other processes"`. Are you sure you're not doing any processing on the JSON object string that may remove these?

Comment: What does `var_dump($data)` show?  Let's make sure the data is right before it's encoded.

Comment: `json_encode` *always* produces valid JSON (DEMO: https://eval.in/56688), there must be something wrong with how you are using it, displaying it, or something else.  Are you sure the JSON you see printed doesn't have the quotes escaped?  Where is it being displayed?

Comment: The var_dump looks normal (edited), says they are arrays.  In the database the structure is just "text".  All I am doing is looping through each row as above, so I don't think I'm processing it in any way.

Comment: PHP 5.4.4-14   So it should be working!

Comment: `string(79) "Allow support for "trends" and other processes"` doesn't look right.  `Allow support for "trends" and other processes` is only ***46 characters***!  There's gotta be some funky unicode characters in there!  Can you `var_dump(str_split($row["Descrption"]));` (and `echo strlen($row["Descrption"])`) for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is the exact JSON output you receive from json_encode, as this should not be happening. A common mistake is looking up the JSON output directly from the page in your browser window, where some kind of parsing might already have happened. I'm guessing that, because of that, HTML entities might be at play here. In that case, try looking up the source of the page (CTRL+U, in most browsers), which should give you a more exact view of what you're receiving.
A tip for in the future: try requesting the output through a JSON viewer (I generally use jsonviewer.stack.hu), it gives you a better idea of what you're dealing with and there are very few things left that could go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode` should do the trick, but only if your PHP version is greater than 5.2. Or else, try escape all json keywords before doing.

```
function escapeJsonString($value) {
    $escapers = array("\\", "/", "\"", "\n", "\r", "\t", "\x08", "\x0c");
    $replacements = array("\\\\", "\\/", "\\\"", "\\n", "\\r", "\\t", "\\f", "\\b");
    $result = str_replace($escapers, $replacements, $value);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: `json_encode` didn't even exist before PHP 5.2, so I don't see how this would help.

Comment: I'm on 5.4.4, no idea why it's not escaping the quotes though! :(

Comment: I means to replace the string `$row["Descrption"]` before given into $data[].

Comment: @RocketHazmat, that's why I am saying "only if...greater than 5.2"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying a simple character substitution? Something like this:

```
$data[] = array(
    "description" => replace ($row["Description"], '"', '\\"'),
);
```

If the double quotes are the ones interferring, that should do the trick...